# CGI output gzip compression module

Tags: python, compression, cgi

Edit: How should I interpret the silence? On a scale from 0 to 10 where 0 means "Bloody awful" and 10 means "Nothing to complain about".

I'm mainly concerned about readability and things I don't seem to be aware of.
If the code is readable, I won't need to explain it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import subprocess

assert __name__ != '__main__'
max_load_avg1 = 3.5

'''
compressout
===========

Simple CGI output module.
Uses gzip compression on the output stream if the client accepts it.

NOTICE: The `cgitb` module will write to stdout if the script crashes,
you should use a browser that does not accept gzip, when you are
testing your scripts.

NOTICE: In the beginning of this file `max_load_avg1` is defined.
This is the maximum allowed load average under one minute.
If the one minute load average exceeds this value, compressout will
abort.


Functions
=========

init(write_headers=True)
------------------------

    Initialize the module.  This function will detect if the client
    supports gzip.
    If `write_headers`, write a 'Vary' and (if used)
    'Content-Encdoing' header.


write_h(s)
----------

    Write part of header.
    Write `s` to standard output, will never go through gzip.


write_b(s)
----------

    Write part of body.

    gzip is supported by the client
    -------------------------------

        `s` will be appended to a local buffer
        which `done` will compress and print.

    gzip is not supported
    ---------------------

        `s` will go straight to stdout.


done()
------

    Done writing output.
    This function will invoke gzip.


Dos and don'ts
==============

## ## ##
if __name__ == '__main__':
    compressout.init()
    main()
    compressout.done()
## ## ##

    * Never call `write_h` after any call to `write_b`
    * Always call `done` when your done.
    * Use only compressout to write output
    * NOTICE: The `cgitb` module will write to stdout if the script
      crashes, you should use a browser that does not accept gzip,
      when you are testing your scripts.
'''

http503_body = '''
Service temporarily unavailable!
Wait at least two minutes before trying again.
Re-attempting prematurely may result in banning your IP address.

-- END OF TRANSMISSION --

'''

def init(write_headers=True):
    '''
    Initialize the module.  This function will detect if the client
    support gzip.
    If `write_headers`, write a 'Vary' and (if used)
    'Content-Encoding' header.
    '''
    global use_gzip
    global body

    # This is the only place where sending a 503 message will work.
    # write_h:
    #   - Message body may need to be compressed.
    #   - Possibility of conflicting Status headers.
    # write_b:
    #   - Message body may need to be compressed.
    #   - Message body may be application/xhtml+xml
    # done:
    #   - Message body needs to be compressed if `use_gzip`.
    #   - Body has already been written if not `use_gzip`.
    if os.getloadavg()[0] > max_load_avg1:
        sys.stdout.write('Status: 503\n')
        sys.stdout.write('Content-Type: text/plain\n')
        sys.stdout.write('Retry-After: 90\n')
        sys.stdout.write(http503_body)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        os.abort()

    use_gzip = 'gzip' in os.getenv('HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING', '')
    body = ''

    if write_headers:
        sys.stdout.write('Vary: Accept-Encoding\n')
        if use_gzip:
            sys.stdout.write('Content-Encoding: gzip\n')


def write_h(s):
    '''
    Write part of header.
    Write `s` to standard output, will never go through gzip.
    '''
    if os.getloadavg()[0] > max_load_avg1: os.abort()

    sys.stdout.write(s)


def write_b(s):
    '''
    Write part of body.

    gzip is supported by the client
    -------------------------------

        `s` will be appended to a local buffer
        which `done` will compress and print.

    gzip is not supported
    ---------------------

        `s` will go straight to stdout.
    '''
    global body

    if os.getloadavg()[0] > max_load_avg1: os.abort()

    if use_gzip:
        body += s
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(s)


def done():
    '''
    Done writing output.
    This function will invoke gzip.
    '''
    if os.getloadavg()[0] > max_load_avg1: os.abort()

    if use_gzip:
        gzip = subprocess.Popen(
            ['gzip'],
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE
        )
        sys.stdout.write(gzip.communicate(body)[0])

use_gzip = True or False
body = ''
```

I realize there are a few things I should have commented when I edited this module a while ago.  But for "correctness" sake, I won't change the code in the question.

The current code can be found at: https://oskog97.com/read/?path=/compressout.py

Comment: Is there any other way than adding for spaces before every line of code?  It's a pain in the ass to insert code in posts here.

Comment: The easiest way to post code is to paste it, highlight it, and press Ctrl-K to mark it as a code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things I've noticed from a quick skim:

- The assert is kinda useless.
- `write_h` and `write_b`?? Documentation isn't an excuse for giving your functions useless names. Name them `write_header` and `write_body` or something.
- Globals? Just no. Especially when they're defined AFTER the functions. Took me like 5 minutes to find them.
- You've copied `if os.getloadavg()[0] > max_load_avg1: os.abort()` tons of times. Might be a good idea to export them to a function.
- `use_gzip = True or False`. ?????????????????????? What ????????????????????????

Comment: Do you have any suggestion what I could use instead of globals?  I know about classes and objects, but I'm trying to get away with "transparent" changes as I've got lots of code that uses this module.

Comment: As a temporary workaround, I've moved them up to right below the doc string and added big shouting warning labels.  ...
 Just for the LOLs: http://www.electricstuff.co.uk/reallydangerous.gif

Comment: Using an object is probably the best solution here, but since you don't want that, just pass the body and gzip as parameters and return tuples from the functions.

Comment: Using an object would actually be easier than doing that.  I'm basically using the entire module as if it was an object.